# DataTables v1.10 sorting by hidden column

Tags: datatables-1.10

After migrating to v1.10 sorting by hidden column stopped working.

Fiddler Example
v1.10
http://jsfiddle.net/0rstgd4f/

```js
var dataTableInfo = $("#dataTable1").DataTable(
    {
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) 
   {
       settings.aoColumns[0].iDataSort = 1;  
      }
    });
```

```html
<table id="dataTable1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Column1
            </th>
            <th style="display:none;">
                Column2
            </th>
            <th>
                Column3
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td style="display:none;">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                a
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td style="display:none;">
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                b
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                3
            </td>
            <td style="display:none;">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                c
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

v.1.8.2
http://jsfiddle.net/rzzrbwb0/

Columns should be sorted as:
1
3
2

or
2
1
3

I tried to use new definition for initComplete as columns(), column() and so on but it did not work.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `initComlete` is the correct place to change DataTables behavior, at least for 1.10. From the [manual](http://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Settings):

> DataTables stores the configuration and data for each table in a
>   settings object. The structure of this object is considered to be
>   private in terms of the DataTables API and reading or writing to the
>   values in the object is not supported. **The property names and values
>   contained within the object can, will and do change between versions!**

If you're using DataTables 1.10, it should be defined using [columns.orderData](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData) or [columnDefs.orderData](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs), see the example below:

```
var dataTableInfo = $("#dataTable1").DataTable({   
   "columnDefs": [
      { "orderData": 1, "targets": [ 0 ] }
   ]        
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rstgd4f/2/) for demonstration.

Comment: This option has not been changed since the old version. It is not applicable in our situation unfortunatelly. We have 100s of pages with reference to the default "script". This is the last option I want to review.

Comment: @Maxim, I have updated my answer. If you can't update all the pages or automate the migration process, your best bet is to stay with the version you're using. From your question I understood that you can edit the code since you've tried newer API like `initComplete`, `column()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that we need to change our code :(